# Checking if the user has logged in the last 24 hours

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I'm currently developing a "user rewarding" system in my website to reward the active users with a given virtual currency (points for example)

I'm having a problem thinking of a way to acomplish that.

I know that I would have to compare timestamps, but I have no idea when I should create the base timestamp, which I would use as the base for my calculations. I think I may not be explaining my question properly, so I will say it in a short manner: How can I check if the user has logged in the last 24 hours. When to create to create the timestamps that I will use for my calculations.

Thank you in advance for all of your answers.

I have  a `last_activity` column in my `users` table

Comment: Add a time column (call it lastLogin) to the user table. The compare the times each time a user logs in. Once the comparison is complete you can update lastLogin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to use some short-hand for this one:

OnRegister (to void giving instant points on first login):

```
user->lastPoints = now();
```

OnLogin:

```
if (user->lastPoints - now > 24h)
{
    if (user->lastPoints - now < 48h)
    {
        user->rewardPoints();
    }
    user->lastPoints = now();
}
```

Hope this is what you're searching for.

Comment: But if he constantly refreshes the page (visits) the timestamp will always be less than 1 day ?

Comment: No, you just update lastPoints inside the `if` (eg. if it's >24h from the last time you awarded points).

Comment: Thank you, I will try out your approach and which i'll select this answer as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well you'd just have to store the timestamps each times your users log in. But if you want to check if they were online no matter if they had to login or not, you'd have implement an update to the timestamp on every page. You should also store the last update time in the cookie of the user so that you don't update at each page load but every ten minutes or what not.

Comment: Ha! We wrote almost the same thing at almost exactly the same time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your application structure, it's hard to be specific, but update a 'last_activity' (or similar) field in your user table on occasion. Then check if that last_activity value is older than 24 hours.

Add some logic so the last_activity only gets updated every 15 minutes or so, and you won't be doing an extra DB write every page load.

Comment: Hey, thank you both (Tom and you) for the quick and helpful answers! There are a couple of things I dont understand: After I stored the last activity timestamp in the database how would I go check if one day has passed? I dont think im being correct, but if he constantly refreshes the page (visits) the timestamp will always be less than 1 day.

Comment: Isn't that what you want? To find out "if the user has logged in the last 24 hours" or not? Well, it that check shows 10 seconds, or 13 minutes, or 23 hours and 59 minutes, then the user has logged in in the last 24 hours.

Comment: @TunaMaxx: I think he wants to award points for consecutive-daily-logins/activity. So if you just refresh the page a hundred times a minute he doesn't want to award points a hundred times, even though the user was technically active in the last 24h.

Comment: So you check once a day to see when the user's last_activity was. If it was less than 24 hours, you increment the 'streak' by a day. If it was more than 24 hours, you break the streak and start again. All you care about is the elapsed time between active sessions, not the number of sessions, right?

Comment: Yes, the time elapsed. But my goal is to reward for activity, not for streaks. Still, that was really helpful as I may implement that in the future :)